# Make image randomly move onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, move

I am attempting to make a image move randomly using plain javascript.
Upon the event onclick the image location should move according to the random number that is generated.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title> Move Image </title>

<style type="text/css">
#smiley { position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeImg()
{
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);


var obj = document.getElementById("emotion");

obj.style.top = x + "px";
obj.style.left = y + "px";


 obj.onclick= "changeImg();"
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="emotion" 
src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" 
width="42" height="42">
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: All the part with `obj` init should not be in the `changeImg` body function, and it should be `obj.onclick=changeImg;`

Answer (score 2):

This one works without inline script in all browsers

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/ronnidc/pen/WvZJBr)

```
var object = document.getElementById('item');

object.onclick=function(){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    object.style.top = x + 'px';
    object.style.left = y + 'px';
};
```

HTML

```
<img id="item" src="http://...png" />
```

CSS

```
#item { 
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You're never assigning `changeImg()` to the `<img>`

  ```
  <img ... onclick="changeImg()">
  ```
- The element must be `position: absolute` if you plan on using `top` and `left`.
- The `<img>` tag has the ID of `emotion`, not `smiley`.
- You don't need to set the `<img>`'s `onclick` property each time the `changeImg()` function is called. Once is enough.

Comment: I thought I was in getElementById?  Thanks!

Comment: @user2138152, but you're never calling the function, and the code inside it that assigns itself to the `<img>` is never executed.

Comment: how would I do that? sorry just confused

Comment: @user2138152, one way to do it is as I explained in the example. Yes, another way is to use `getElementById()` to find the element, then set the `onclick` attribute to the `changeImg` function. But where are you doing that?

Comment: can I call it inside the html tag? <img onclick = "changeimg()";

Comment: @user2138152, yes, you can do that.

Comment: so  obj.onclick= "changeImg();" inside the script does not call it? im just confused as to why that wont and insde the html will. thanks

Comment: @user2138152, that would work, if you execute it. But where are you executing that piece of code? From what I see, you're defining a function, named `changeImg()`, that contains the piece of code. But the function never gets called. And if the function never gets called, the piece of code never gets executed.

Comment: @user2138152, right above the script tag I see the end of the function (`}`)... The entire script consists of a single function definition.

Comment: oh gotcha so have the  obj.onclick= changeImg(); outisde the function?

Comment: @user2138152, yes, you should move that outside the function. Then, the script would contain a function definition and a statement. Do note however that you also need to define `obj` before using it. If you move only that line outside the function, then you'd end up with a function and a statement referring to an unknown variable named `obj`, so you need to copy the part where `obj` gets what `getElementById()` returns, too.

Comment: ah I see, got it working now.  The html section had not yet been loaded into the DOM as well so there was no smiley to refer to in the javascript.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You never set the position of the image object. Instead, you set "smiley" to relative, but the image is "emotion".

Try

```
#emotion{ position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
```

I would suggest you to call the function rather than the string literal.
example:

```
obj.onclick = changeImg;
```

Comment: ah so not in quotes? my teacher explained it as such.... obj.onclick = "changeImg()";

Comment: @user2138152 using quotes will `eval` the string which is typically not what you want; just using a function is better

Comment: @user2138152, when you say `obj.onclick = 'changeImg()'`, you're instructing the browser to evaluate the following script when the image is clicked: `changeImg()`. If you say `obj.onclick = changeImg`, then you're binding the function `changeImg` itself to the element's `onclick` attribute. In the end, both will do the same thing, but in different ways.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head><title> Move Image </title>

<style type="text/css">
#emotion { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeImg()
{
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);


var obj = document.getElementById("emotion");

obj.style.top = x + "px";
obj.style.left = y + "px";


 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="emotion" 
src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" 
width="150" height="42" onclick="changeImg()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not just dump code but explain what you have done and why.